# Can you give me a walk through of proof for Fermat's last theorem?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Proof for Fermat's last theorem was presented in year '96 by British mathematician, it is said to be "a very long proof and involves latest advances in mathematics", can anyone please suggest what mathematical branches  are required for understanding the proof ?

Comment: Everything is needed, and that is not enough.

Comment: @marty cohen awesome comment with which I heartily concur

Comment: A few strong grad students in algebraic number theory at my university told me they understand most of the proof. I think it's self-defeating to regard the proof as being some sort of other-worldly math not comprehensible to anyone but a select few 'geniuses', which is the sentiment I seem to be getting from some.

Comment: Turns out your question was four months early :) [Kenneth A. Ribet, "A 2020 View of Fermat's Last Theorem"](http://youtu.be/mq9BS6S2E2k)

Answer (score 4):

There are many accessible sources that talk about the history of the problem: A superb popular book (Fermat’s Enigma, Singh), an elementary number theoretic book (Fermat’s Last Theorem for Amateurs, Ribenboim), a BBC documentary (Fermat’s Last Theorem), and even several youtube numberphile videos that could guide you in the right direction.

As far as the actual math used by Wiles, most of these sources echo the same general sentiment: you might spend your time more wisely obtaining a PhD.

> BBC Interviewer: “Could you explain *modular forms* in one sentence?”
>
> John Conway: “Hahahahaha”

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahaaha

Comment: Modular forms and L-functions are the algebraic arithmetic analytic generalization of $\zeta(s)$ starting from that $\Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2} \zeta(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $\theta(x) = \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ which is analytic, $2i$-periodic and satisfies $\theta(x)=x^{-1/2}\theta(1/x)$ which is a very restrictive condition

Comment: Isn't the answer to the BBC question "No."?